# use Linux Strace command inside Java program

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, strace

I wanted to call Linux command "Strace" to monitor the system calls for an anroid Operating system. is there a way to call Strace command inside a java program for Andorid Mobile App Development.

Comment: I don't think `strace` is generally delivered on Android user devices. You could try including your own (or writing your own functionality with `ptrace` in JNI), but I'm not sure it will work well even then...

Answer (score 0):

The code would be:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("strace "+ /*rest of the command*/);
```

You can then read the output from The process' `InputStream`. You can get that using `p.getInputStream()`.

Comment: Note that you'll probably only be permitted to trace your own process. And if you do, I'd be worried that each read from that input stream causes a new event, which lets you read, which causes a new event, which lets you read, which... and so on. You should be able to avoid that by giving the proper args to strace to make it filter out reads.

Comment: May i know Is there any other way for monitoring system call needed for different Android application?

Comment: AFAIK, you will need to build your own custom ROM with that. I highly doubt you can do such a thing even with root access.